# TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 53 in laravel 5 while uploading a .csv file

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am reading a csv file and sending the contents to database. I get tokenmismatch error even though I tried mentioning the csrf token.

Comment: could you please share your code, where you got error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSRF tokens are only placed on routes that handle form submissions. I think its likely that you are reading the CSV and saving in the database that doesn't require you to submit a CSRF token, I would recommend to place that route where CSRF token is disabled so it doesn't require you to submit a CSRF token. You can do that by doing something like this.

In your App/Http/Midlleware folder go to VerifyCsrfToken.php and include the specific route to the exception as follows:

```
/**
 * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $except = [
    'csvParserRoute',
];
```

This will disable the CSRF token requirement for this route only and the error should go away.

Comment: could you be more specific ? I tried this it didn't work. Is there anything else I should do along with this ?

Comment: also after adding this exception be sure to clear you route cache. Do this 

" php artisan route:cache"   If you add your code, we can have a better understanding about what you are trying to do.

I would start by posting the blade html template and the controller it is pointing too.

Comment: The file is too big to display here. Also " php artisan route:cache" gave an error "unable to prepare route [admin/login2] for serialization. Uses closure". And yet i tried, still gave me the tokenmismatch error.

Comment: you are using a route that is from laravel 4 in laravel 5  change your route [admin/login2] first to something like this 

Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/why-unable-to-prepare-route-for-serialization-uses-closure - closures are no longer supported in L5

Answer (score 0):

Try below snippet in your view:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="<?php echo csrf_token(); ?>">
```

**OR**

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

If that doesn't work then, comment this line:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class
```

in app/Http/Kernel.php file.

Since this VerifyCsrfToken Middleware makes it easy to protect your application from cross-site request forgery (CSRF) attacks. It's *not recommended* to comment that line, But for testing purpose you can do that.

See, if that works.

Comment: The first thing didn't work. The second did, but I wanted a solution to the csrf token mismatch, I don't want to entirely remove it.

Comment: @PiyaDesai Try newly added option